# Tumblr API paging bug when fetching followers?

Tags: python, api, tumblr

I'm writing a little python app to fetch the followers of a given tumblr, and I think I may have found a bug in the paging logic.

The tumblr I am testing with has 593 followers and I know the API is block limited to 20 per call. After successful authentication, the fetch logic looks like this:

```
offset = 0
while True:
    response = client.followers(blog, limit=20, offset=offset)
    bunch = len(response["users"])
    if bunch == 0:
        break
    j = 0
    while j < bunch:
        print response["users"][j]["name"]
        j = j + 1
    offset += bunch
```

What I observe is that on the third call into the API with `offset=40`, the first name returned on the list is one I saw in the previous group. It's actually the 38th name. This behavior (seeing one or more names I've seen before) repeats randomly from that point on, though not in every call to the API. Some calls give me a fresh 20 names. It's repeatable across multiple test runs. The sequence I see them in is the same as on Tumblr's site, I just see many of them twice.

An interesting coincidence is that the total number of of non-unique followers returned is the same as what the "Followers" count indicates on the blog itself (593). But only 516 of them are unique.

For what it's worth, running the query on Tumblr's console page returns the same results regardless of the language I choose, so I'm not inclined to think this is a bug in the PyTumblr client, but something lower, at the API level.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had this same problem when fetching using PHP and never found a way around it. Even when loading pages of followers on Tumblr itself, it will have discrepancies.

Comment: To clarify: I never found a way to fetch all of the followers without having to sort and remove duplicates from the list to get a unique set in the end.

Comment: Yep. After some further googling, it seems like others see this, too, and it may have something to do with how they mark spam users. Looks like some additional work to make the results unique is required.